# setup tls connection between glassfish app server and mysql instance in amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, glassfish-4, tls1.2

I have been trying to figure out how to setup secure TLS connection between my app server(Glassfish) on Amazon EC2 and the MySQL instance on Amazon RDS. Docs online do not indicate in detail or are misleading. Can anyone please guide me in the right direction or links to any good articles that i could look into.

PS: I have tried the steps in the following link: [https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50287_01/doc.80/e50288/sg_imp_security.htm#ADBSG136]  but does not seem to apply for amazon deployed servers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to skip the first few steps in that documentation you linked. First go [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html) and download the appropriate RDS SSL certificate. Then continue with your tutorial around step #5 where they have you install the certificate in the Java keystore.